# Using a decorator for init in Python3+Pyside6, to avoid writing boilerplate code

Tags: python, wrapper, pyqt, pyside, decorator-pattern

I'm building a GUI application with Python3+Pyside6 and have many `QDialog` classes that are similar, and i was looking for a way to avoid having to rewrite the same code when initializing them. The code below is one solution to this

**This code creates a python decorator `modal_dialog_init` to avoid having to write boilerplate code when initializing classes with similar `__init__` functions**

(An alternative solution is to use inheritance, but then i could not have code both before and after: Putting the call to `super()` at the beginning or end of the `__init__` function)

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6 import QtGui


def modal_dialog_init(i_init_function):
    def init_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setModal(True)
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("init_wrapper, before __init__")
        self.vbox.addWidget(label)

        i_init_function(self)  # <-------------------

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("init_wrapper, after __init__")
        self.vbox.addWidget(label)

        for arg in args:
            print(f"{arg}")
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            print(f"{k}: {v}")

        self.button_box = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Close, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            self
        )
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button_box)
        self.button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        self.adjustSize()

    return init_wrapper


def start(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    dlg = cls(*args, **kwargs)
    dlg.exec()
    return None


class AboutDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    @modal_dialog_init
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("during __init__ --- About this application")
        self.vbox.addWidget(label)


class SystemInfoDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    @modal_dialog_init
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("during __init__ --- System info")
        self.vbox.addWidget(label)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    qapplication = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    start(AboutDialog, "test-arg", param1="test-kw-arg-1", param2="test-kw-arg-2")
    start(SystemInfoDialog, "another-test")
    sys.exit(qapplication.exec())
```

Running the code:

- Dependencies:

  - Python 3.10
  - `pip install Pyside6`
- To illustrate i've added two example `QDialog` classes. When the application is run the first is shown, and only once that is closed is the next dialog shown

I'm mainly interested in how this code can be improved in terms of maintainability, readability, elegance. And as a side issue if there are other (better) ways of achieving the same thing (for example other design patterns)

Grateful for your thoughts on this!

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: This might be a good question if you follow our guidelines starting with [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).